# No row indentation for items in ListView

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview

I'm currently working on some software and the customer is dead-set on a specific UI change that has been giving me some trouble:

I would like items in a ListView to not have any indentation. To illustrate I changed the backcolor of the ListView and the items.

[image: The problem]]

Now, the little piece to the left of each item should also be white. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the [`OwnerDraw`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.ownerdraw(v=vs.110).aspx) property of `ListView` to `true` and using `DrawItem`, `DrawColumnHeader` and `DrawSubItem` draw the list view yourself.

**For example:**

```
private void listView1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.DrawString(e.Item.Text, e.Item.Font, Brushes.Black, 
         new Rectangle(e.Bounds.Left-2, e.Bounds.Top, e.Bounds.Width, e.Bounds.Height));
}

private void listView1_DrawColumnHeader(object sender, DrawListViewColumnHeaderEventArgs e)
{
    e.DrawDefault = true;
}

private void listView1_DrawSubItem(object sender, DrawListViewSubItemEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.ColumnIndex>0)
        e.DrawDefault = true;
}
```

**Note:**

- *The above rendering is just an example* and shows you how you can draw item text in desired location for example using using [`Graphics.DrawString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.drawstring(v=vs.110).aspx).
- Also it shows you how to set `e.DrawDefault = true;` to perform default rendering.
- The first subitem of each ListViewItem object represents the parent item itself
- To avoid issues with graphics flickering when owner drawing, override the `ListView` control and set the `DoubleBuffered` property to true.
- To learn more, read documents of [`OwnerDraw`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.ownerdraw(v=vs.110).aspx) property of `ListView` control.