# Remove space between left ListView border and column items

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, listviewitem

[image]

I colored a few items of the first `ListView` column by

```
foreach (ListViewItem lvi in listView.Items)
{
    lvi.UseItemStyleForSubItems = false;

    lvi.SubItems[0].BackColor = Color.DarkMagenta;
}
```

and try to get rid of the outlined gap between the left `ListView` border and the column items.

Setting `listView.Padding` has no effect, `ColumnHeader` class has neither a `BackColor` property nor a `Margin` property which could be set below zero.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is not enough info to reproduce your issue.  Please take a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You can enlarge the gap by chosing a suitable smallimagelist but I doubt you can get rid of it, maybe ownerdraing would help, though..

Comment: As also mentioned by @TaW owner-drawing is what you are looking for. For example you can take a look at this post which seems to be a duplicate: [No row indentation for items in ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34875335/no-row-indentation-for-items-in-listview)

Comment: I didn't see any difference when setting the left border < 0 so I kept the bounds as they are..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Owner-Drawing will let you paint the whole Item background as you like.

```
listView1.OwnerDraw = true;
```

Here is a simple, minimal  example:

```
private void listView1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    using (Brush brush = new SolidBrush(
            (e.State.HasFlag(ListViewItemStates.Focused)) ? 
            SystemColors.Highlight : e.Item.BackColor))
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, e.Bounds);
    e.DrawText();
}
```

Note that once you owner draw the item you will aslo need to owner-draw the sub-items and the headers, even if you just use the defaults:

```
private void listView1_DrawSubItem(object sender, DrawListViewSubItemEventArgs e)
{
    e.DrawDefault = true;
}

private void listView1_DrawColumnHeader(object sender, DrawListViewColumnHeaderEventArgs e)
{
    e.DrawDefault = true;
}
```